# Select Top N Records Ordered by X, But Have Results in Reverse Order

Tags: sql, selection

I'm trying to get the top N records (when ordered by some column X), but have the result set in reverse order. The following statement is **incorrect**, but probably demonstrates what I'm after:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X DESC) ORDER BY X ASC
```

For example, column X could be an ID or a timestamp; I want the latest 10 records but want them returned in forward chronological order.

Comment: Why not `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X ASC` ?

Comment: @Dor  Because then I would get the latest 10 records, but they'd be returned in reverse chronological order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X DESC) as myAlias 
ORDER BY X ASC
```

i.e. you might need an alias on your subquery, but other than that it should work.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Although I don't quite get why SQL demands an alias when there's no reference to it elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X DESC) temp  --alias
ORDER BY X
```

or with a common table expression (CTE)

```
WITH Temp AS (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X DESC) 

SELECT * FROM temp 
ORDER BY X
```

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY clause is used to order the RESULT SET by a specified column.

Your query 
`Select TOP 10 * from FooTable ORDER BY X DESC` assuming X is the timestamp ,is not going to return the most recently inserted 10 rows. It will return the top 10 rows as stored (in whichever order) in the Database, and will then return the result set of the 10 such rows , in descending order.
Hence your subquery should be modified to

`Select TOP 10 * from (Select * from FooTable ORDER BY DESC) as T`

This should fulfill your first requirement. You may then use this result set as an alias, to decide your final sort order.

I hope i have understood you correctly, when you say "*I'm trying to get the top N records (when ordered by some column X)*"

Comment: The error is "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution to this question for all non-supported versions for **TOP** keyword is to use **LIMIT**.
Example :-

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM FooTable ORDER BY X DESC LIMIT 10) as myAlias 
ORDER BY X ASC
```