# Performance regarding selecting last n records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

I am querying table to select last n records but preserving the order. For this, I am using the following query which I got from [Select Top N Records Ordered by X, But Have Results in Reverse Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572496/select-top-n-records-ordered-by-x-but-have-results-in-reverse-order):

```
WITH    Temp
          AS ( SELECT TOP 10
                        [TestID] ,
                        UserID ,
                        DateSent
               FROM     [Test]
               WHERE    UserID = @UserID
               ORDER BY DateSent DESC
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Temp
    ORDER BY DateSent
```

i.e I am selecting the last n records while preserving the sort order. Below is the dummy scripts to create the above tables:

```
    GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
    (
      [TestID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     NOT NULL ,
      [UserID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DateSent] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_TestID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [TestID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Test_UserID_DateSent] ON [dbo].[Test] 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    DateSent DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


GO

INSERT INTO [Test]
SELECT TOP 100000 ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %10),
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1 - FLOOR(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(4))) * 365.25 * 90), 0)
FROM   master..spt_values 
GO
```

Above I have created the table, applied index on it and inserted some dummy data in it. I am executing this query to get the records:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
SET @UserID = 1 ;
WITH    Temp
          AS ( SELECT TOP 10
                        [TestID] ,
                        UserID ,
                        DateSent
               FROM     [Test]
               WHERE    UserID = @UserID
               ORDER BY DateSent DESC
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Temp
    ORDER BY DateSent
```

Below is the execution plan after running the above query:

[image]

As you can see the index is following but for inner query and you can see in the index plan that 77% of the execution is taken by the Sort process. **How can I avoid that?** What index should I apply here to overcome this situation.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But can I change my query or make some different index to apply the index for that 10 records too?

Comment: See my answer which address that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left-most sort which is consuming 77% of the execution plan is only working on your `TOP 10` records. You can verify this by removing the final `ORDER BY`:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT
SET @UserID = 1 ;
WITH    Temp
          AS ( SELECT TOP 10
                        [TestID] ,
                        UserID ,
                        DateSent
               FROM     [Test]
               WHERE    UserID = @UserID
               ORDER BY DateSent DESC
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Temp
    --ORDER BY DateSent
```

It should be mentioned that all operators in a plan must add up to 100%.  If your cheapest operation (i.e. sorting only 10 records) is consuming most of the execution time, then I'd say you're in good shape.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking to overcome that Sort Operator too probably to apply some index for that operator too?

Comment: @RockySingh The point is that you can't reduce all operations to 0%. The work has to be done somewhere. Since your sort is on a materialized table (the CTE) I don't know that an index could ever be used. Even so, it's only for **10 rows**. How much will that really improve execution time?

Comment: Actually the nubmers always are 100%. It is not "expensive" per se, it is "how large a part of the time was spent there". If you reduce the index seek - where do you think the 100% go - somewhere else. It must be fast enough AND the time where it spends time must make sense. Here it does - data access via index. But the numbers ALWAYS end up as 100 - it is RELATIVE weight, not absolute.